# Installing GD Library on Centos 6.7 and PHP 5.4

Tags: centos, php, centos6, yum, gd

Versions:
centos-release-6-7.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64
PHP 5.4.45

1. Installed GD using yum:

> $ yum install php54w-gd

Installed: php54w-gd.x86_64 0:5.4.45-2.w6

2. Restarted:

> $ service httpd restart

3. Checked

> Running: $ rpm -qa | grep php

I get:

```
php54-php-common-5.4.40-2.el6.x86_64
php54-php-pear-1.9.4-10.el6.noarch
php54w-common-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
php54w-pear-1.10.1-1.w6.noarch
php54w-devel-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
rhscl-php54-epel-6-x86_64-1-2.noarch
php54w-cli-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
php54w-mbstring-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
php54w-pdo-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
php54w-mcrypt-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
wbm-php-pear-1.5-1.noarch
php54-runtime-2.0-1.el6.x86_64
php54-php-cli-5.4.40-2.el6.x86_64
php54-php-process-5.4.40-2.el6.x86_64
php54-php-pdo-5.4.40-2.el6.x86_64
php54-2.0-1.el6.x86_64
php54w-xml-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
php54-php-xml-5.4.40-2.el6.x86_64
php54-php-mysqlnd-5.4.40-2.el6.x86_64
php54-php-mbstring-5.4.40-2.el6.x86_64
php54w-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
php54w-mysql-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
php54w-process-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
php54w-gd-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64
```

so `php54w-gd-5.4.45-2.w6.x86_64` is listed...

However running `phpinfo()` no sign of GD library...

Comment: You installed two completely different builds of PHP from two different sources. Get rid of one of them.

Comment: uninstalled `php54w` but there doesn't seem to be `php54-gd` ... `No package php54-gd available.`

Comment: You'll find it if you get the package name correct. I certainly have it on my local mirror... `/srv/www/mirrors/centos/6.7/sclo/x86_64/rh/php54/php54-php-gd-5.4.40-3.el6.x86_64.rpm`

Comment: Amazing that totally worked, I installed `yum php54-php-gd` restarted and all is well. If you put that in an answer I will happily accept. Thank you.

Comment: check php version `rpm -qa | grep php` and  then install `yum install gd gd-devel php-gd`. and check `php -i | grep -i --color gd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running PHP? If you're running it in FCGI mode with an external spawner, restarting nginx will have no effect on the PHP server, so you'll need to restart that separately.

Answer (score 0):

You need restart php-fpm (if use this)
Or web server to affect Gd 
Also check php.ini for this line:
Extensions: Gd.so

Answer (score 0):

Your system has two completely different and incompatible builds of PHP installed, one from Webtatic and one from Software Collections.

Remove all the packages from one and install the PHP GD package from the other. The package name in Software Collections follows the same format as the rest of them: `php54-php-gd`.